# "1" key gets registered as spacebar on external keyboard

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

My external keyboard (from a average company in my country) registers the key <kbd>1</kbd> as <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> (checked using keyboard tester). It's a 60% mechanical keyboard, I have tried resetting the keyboard using it's software, re-installed the software as well as the drivers, checked the input & language settings of Windows. I even used it with other devices to confirm this issue.

However, when I use <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>,the keyboard does register it as <kbd>F1</kbd> (meaning the key itself is working).

All other keys are working perfectly fine.

Is there a way to hard reset (clean the internal memory) the keyboard using Windows? The keyboard is still under warranty and I have already raised a complaint.

Comment: I've had a mechanical keyboard with similar symptom, where one of the surface-mount diodes on the PC board came loose.  By sheer luck, I heard the tiny part rattling in the case, noticed the empty solder pads and replaced it with a small diode with leads. Whether or not that is your keyboard's problem is a guess.

Comment: There was a software glitch that the keyboard stored on its memory, I had to hard reset the keyboard to solve the issue. Thanks for your help!